# Neighbourhood of set that contains infinity

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, functions, metric-spaces

If $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}$, is there a metric on $A\cup \{\infty\}$ such that all neighbourhoods of $\infty$ don't contain $(a,\infty)\cap A$ for some $a\in A$?

Motivation for my question is necessity of definition of the limit of a sequence, because if answer to my question is 'no' we could look at sequences as functions with domain $\mathbb{N}\subset\mathbb{N}\cup\{\infty\}$, and for any metric on $\mathbb{N}\cup\{\infty\}$ we could tell for sure that neighbourhood of $\infty$ contains $(n,\infty)$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$, and therefore we could only define the limit of a function.

Comment: Have you been introduced to topological spaces? And I don't understand what you want. Do you want that for all neighborhood of $∞$, there exists some $a$ such that $(a,∞)∩A$ is not in that neighborhood? In other words, for all neighborhood, there is a point not contained in it… I don't understand, don't you want that $(a,∞)∩A$ *is* in the neighborhood?

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. If you write something of the form "for all $x$, something or other, for some $y$", that could mean $\forall x \exists y(\mbox{something or other})$ or $\exists y\forall x(\mbox{something or other})$. The order of the quantifiers matters. What do you mean?